# Groovy Regex Closure

Tags: regex, grails, groovy, closures

In my Grails controller, I'm trying to get a collection of paths to image files from the database as a collection of objects. The only way I know how to pass data from a controller to a view in Grails is as a map, so I convert the objects into a map.

I need to strip the path so that I can get the filename only, then in the view I can add the correct/new path to the filename to link the files.

This seems like a good job for a closure--am I mistaken in this?--but I'm not sure how to write a regex inside a closure.

Thanks for any help!

```
private Map getMap() {
    Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)

    // Query DB to get image paths
    def result = sql.rows("""   SELECT image_path
                                FROM images
                                WHERE display=TRUE """)

    // Convert results into a map that can be more easily parsed in the view
    def gallery = result.collectEntries {
        [imagePath: it.image_path] 
    }

    gallery.each() { key, value -> /* regex goes here */ }
    return gallery
}
```

Comment: 1: why are you doing raw SQL calls? 2: you probably need `collect ` not each

Comment: The raw SQL calls are not my choice. I'm in the process of getting us to move to using GORM, but right now SQL calls are required for 'code consistency' across older projects.

Comment: you can also use a regexp in your SQL query and put `distinct` to get the unique values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect time for some collection closure =)

```
private Map getMap() {
    Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)

    // Query DB to get image paths
    def result = sql.rows("""   SELECT image_path
                                FROM images
                                WHERE display=TRUE """)

    // Convert results into a map that can be more easily parsed in the view
    def gallery = result.collect{ [imgKey : it.image_path] } 

    //why not just use File.name instead of regex
    gallery.collect() { key, imgPath -> [key, new File(imgPath).name] }
    return gallery
}
```

Comment: Remember that the file constructor doesn't actually create a file--it represents something in your system that may or may not exist. Since you just want the name, I think it is a good candidate to promote some cleaner code

Comment: I'm still not sure I'm understanding how to use collections correctly. Implementing your code I ran into some type errors. The gallery.collect closure said there was no version applicable for a LinkedHashMap (values: [[imgKey:maps/foo.jpg]]). I eventually also had to change the method to return an ArrayList, which fortunately worked ok with the grails view. I did manage to do all the work in a single collect closure though, like in the following comment.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: `private ArrayList getImages() {
    Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)

    def result = sql.rows("""   SELECT image_path FROM images WHERE display=TRUE """)

    def gallery = result.collect{ [image : new File(it.image_path).name] }

    return gallery
}`
Ugh. Dislike StackOverflow's lack of indenting in comments.